# When is it safe to update the UI?

Tags: android

I feel like this should have been answered by the documentation in the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class, but I'm still not positive -- when is it actually safe to update the UI of an Activity (or a Fragment)? Only when the activity is resumed, or any point between being started and stopped?

For example, the `Activity` docs state:

> The visible lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onStart() until a corresponding call to onStop(). During this time the user can see the activity on-screen, though it may not be in the foreground and interacting with the user. Between these two methods you can maintain resources that are needed to show the activity to the user. For example, you can register a BroadcastReceiver in onStart() to monitor for changes that impact your UI, and unregister it in onStop() when the user no longer sees what you are displaying. The onStart() and onStop() methods can be called multiple times, as the activity becomes visible and hidden to the user.

From that reading, I would assume that even if a foreground dialog is displaying, I can safely update UI elements behind it.

**EDIT**
To clarify: the reason I ask is having been bitten by errors when firing off an AsyncTask, and attempting to update the UI in the `onPostExecute` method. Even though it runs on the UI thread, the user has navigated away from that view and I would receive an exception. I'm starting a new project now and trying to establish some guidelines around better `AsyncTask` idioms.

Comment: yes you can update the UI from call of onStart() to onStop(). And I have implemented the same feature where user interact with the dialog while the UI element behind it was getting updated. So I can say it works perfectly.

Comment: what kind of update you want to perform is it updating data? or updating view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this comes down to what you mean by "safe" to update the UI. For elements on the Activity screen, they can be updated whenever, even if your Activity is not in the foreground (but make sure to update from the UI Thread).

However, the issue that will trip you up is saving state: `onSaveInstanceState`.

As you may know, the Activity that is in the background may be destroyed by the OS to free up memory. It will then be re-created when you come back to it. During this process, the `onSaveInstanceState` method will be called. If the OS does destroy the Activity, **any changes you made to the UI State after the call to onSaveInstanceState will not be persisted**.

For Fragments, you will actually get an IllegalStateException if you try to commit a `FragmentTransaction` after `onSaveInstanceState`. [More info on that.](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

To summarize, you can update the UI of your activity at any point and try to gracefully handle the Fragment issues, but you *may* lose these updates when the Activity is restored.

So, you could say that it is only truly safe to update the Activity while it is in the foreground, or rather, before the call to `onSaveInstanceState`.

**Edit in regards to Async Task onPostExectue**

This is likely related to the issue I am referring to above with Fragment State Loss. From the blog post I linked to:

> Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods. This includes commonly used methods such as AsyncTask#onPostExecute() and LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks#onLoadFinished(). The problem with performing transactions in these methods is that they have no knowledge of the current state of the Activity lifecycle when they are called. For example, consider the following sequence of events:
>
> 1. An activity executes an AsyncTask.
> 2. The user presses the "Home" key, causing the activity's onSaveInstanceState() and onStop() methods to be called.
> 3. The AsyncTask completes and onPostExecute() is called, unaware that the Activity has since been stopped.
> 4. A FragmentTransaction is committed inside the onPostExecute() method, causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: See my edit above -- I've had issues with attempting to change activities and fragments that the user has navigated away from when an AsyncTask completes, and was wondering when that view may no longer be touched.

Comment: Fragments will definitely be a problem, see my edit above. Also, be very careful using AsyncTasks as an inner class inside your Activity. It will hold an implicit strong reference to the outer Activity, but that Activity could be destroyed by the OS. Bad things can happen there.

Comment: That makes sense. I knew the AsyncTask would retain the enclosing instance, which I want to avoid anyways from a memory use perspective, but it also helps to hear the other downsides. I'm not really seeing sufficient upsides to AsyncTask over the regular java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: AsyncTasks are better if you can use them outside of the Activity. I would say that the problem is not so much with AsyncTask as it is with the Activity Lifecycle. And unfortunately, if you use the AsyncTask the way that some of Google's own tutorials show, you run into these kinds of issues.